# Ошибка при прочтении файла: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 529: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, unicode

Хочу открыть txt файл для обработки, получаю ошибку: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0, там все в юникоде, но могут присутствовать вот такие строки, как сделать чтобы python не интерпретировал их как байты?  может я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: добавьте вывод ошибки и способ, которым вы открываете файл.

Comment: example = open('test.txt', 'r')
example.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 529: invalid continuation byte

Comment: В какой кодировке текст в файл сохранён? Создайте минимальный пример файла, который к ошибке ведёт и добавьте в ответ байты как есть: `print(open("text.txt", "rb").read())`

Answer (score -1):

```
with codecs.open(file_name, "r",encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fdata:
```

Comment: не очень понимаю как работать с этой конструкцией

Comment: Не следует codecs использовать. У автора обычный open() читает Unicode (что на Python 3 указывает). Можно туда обработчик ошибок указать. Даже на Питоне 2.7 следует io.open вместо codecs.open в большинстве случаев использовать.